# Wi-Fi drops out about a minute after restarting adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, adapter

My wireless adapter almost never works. When I restart it, it works for about one minute before dropping from 3-out-of-4 bars to 1 bar and 100% packet loss. It does not connect to my local network either. It is a Realtek-based ALFA AWUS036NHR v2. It is possibly interference but my other devices (phone and tablet) work from the same distance. How would I check for interference. Also I am on mode g with 2.4 ghz I believe and I am the floor above the router and about 20-30 feet away, and the router auto-sets the channel. When I go to the realtek driver software, I disable the adapter and reenable it. It then worrks for a few minutes at 3 bars then drops back down. The problem is prbably not interference because other devices work.

Comment: Have you checked for wireless interference? I think your Wi-Fi is being stepped on.

Comment: That may be but my other devices (phone and tablet) work from the same distance. How would I check?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include that. Giving incomplete information in a question will generate incorrect answers, which tend to be guesses since not all information is provided. You need to include _all_ relevant information in your question.

Comment: Ok done I added all that I figured out based on the comment.